# Child views in a custom viewgroup not following boundaries

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating a custom layout (viewgroup subclass) that divides the itself into cells, then positions child layouts based on their cell position and cell width/height.

Think of it like how widgets are organized.

I added a bunch of frame layouts with different background colors, and they seem to position correctly. However when I put in a textview, it expands well beyond that vertically and stays at a fixed width horizontally. The position works correctly though.

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class DynamicLayout extends ViewGroup {

int numCellsX = 6, numCellsY = 8;
int cellSize;

int blockMap[];

public DynamicLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public DynamicLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public DynamicLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    blockMap = new int[numCellsX * numCellsY];
    clearBlockMap();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    cellSize = getMeasuredWidth() / numCellsX;

    int specWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int specHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    this.setMeasuredDimension(specWidth, specHeight);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (getChildCount() > 0) {
        int wspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredWidth()
                / getChildCount(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        int hspec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getMeasuredHeight(),
                MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.measure(wspec, hspec);
        }
    }
    Log.i("DYNA", "Measured");
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    Log.i("DYNA", "On Layout");

    clearBlockMap();

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = getChildAt(i);

        if (v instanceof DynaServiceView) {
            DynaServiceView serviceView = (DynaServiceView) v;

            if (serviceView.getVisibility() == GONE) 
                continue;


            int x = serviceView.getXPos();
            int y = serviceView.getYPos();
            int width = serviceView.getXCells();
            int height = serviceView.getYCells();

            //Is the thing too big?
            if (width > numCellsX)
            {
                Log.i("DYNA", "Warning, service too big, shrinking to size");
                width = numCellsX;
                serviceView.setWidth(width);
            }

            //Is there space?
            if (checkBlockMap(x, y, width, height))
            {
                Log.i("DYNA", "Found collision at child " + i +", resolving...");
                //Find somewhere to put this
                boolean foundSpot = false;
                for (int j = y; j <= numCellsY - height; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = x; k <= numCellsX - width; k++)
                    {
                        if (!checkBlockMap(k, j, width, height))
                        {
                            x = k;
                            y = j;                              
                            foundSpot = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (foundSpot)
                        break;
                }

                if (!foundSpot)                 
                    Log.i("DYNA", "No spot for child at: " + i + ", skipping!");
                else
                    Log.i("DYNA", "Resolved! New X/Y: " + x + ", " + y);
            }

            setBlockMap(x, y, width, height);

            //Has spot now, set layout
            serviceView.layout(l + (x * cellSize), t + (y * cellSize), (x * cellSize)
                    + (width * cellSize), (y * cellSize)
                    + (height * cellSize));
        }

    }       
}

private boolean checkBlockMap(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    for (int  j= y; j < y + height; j++)
    {
        for (int k = x; k < x + width; k++)                     
            if (blockMap[(j * numCellsX) + k] == 1)
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void setBlockMap(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    for (int  j= y; j < y + height; j++)
    {
        for (int k = x; k < x + width; k++)                     
            blockMap[(j * numCellsX) + k] = 1;
    }
}

private void clearBlockMap()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < blockMap.length;i++)
        blockMap[i] = 0;
}
}
```

Here is a picture explaining the problem. On the right you can see the layout's borders line up correctly, however on the left it's obvious that the child text view is not following it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue.... onMeasure wasn't setup correctly. Stupid mistake.

Comment: I'm looking into doing something very similar to this.  Out of curiosity, what does the XML layout look like when using this, or are you using this ViewGroup programatically?

Comment: They layout was all in program, but you could use said layout like a linear or relative layout, which the pictures were taken from.

The Android GUI editor is advance enough that it will run the code just in time and show what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I decided to use margins computed for items at runtime for views within a RelativeLayout.  It is probably less efficient, but until I find a reason to swap out the layout, I'll probably go with it for now.